# No route found for "GET /user/register": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)

Tags: php, symfony

When i go to : `http://mysite.com/web/app_dev.php/user/register`

I am getting:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException: No route found for "GET /user/register": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)
```

Here is my code:

```
MainUserBundle_register:
    pattern:  /user/register/
    defaults: { _controller: MainUserBundle:UserAuthWebService:register, _format:json}
    requirements:
        _method:  POST
```

my controller is:

```
 public function registerAction($email="test", $username="test", $password="test123")
    {


       //some code

    }
```

Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can restrict a route to only match a given HTTP method. In the code you posted the route will only match `POST` requests. You will need to allow `POST` and `GET`, or remove the requirement all together.

```
MainUserBundle_register:
    pattern:  /user/register/
    defaults: { _controller: MainUserBundle:UserAuthWebService:register, _format:json}
    requirements:
        _method:  POST|GET
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-http-method-requirements

Comment: Sometimes this error arrise when you have an error in your controller or the twig element that is going to be rendered