# How to solve the error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, symfony

I am using Symfony to connect with Google Plus. Here is my code about connecting google after login and get access token:

```
$app->match('/connect', function (Request $request) use ($app, $client) {
$token = $app['session']->get('token');

if (empty($token)) {
    // Ensure that this is no request forgery going on, and that the user
    // sending us this connect request is the user that was supposed to.
    if ($request->get('state') != ($app['session']->get('state'))) {
        return new Response('Invalid state parameter', 401);
    }

    // Normally the state would be a one-time use token, however in our
    // simple case, we want a user to be able to connect and disconnect
    // without reloading the page.  Thus, for demonstration, we don't
    // implement this best practice.
    //$app['session']->set('state', '');

    $code = $request->getContent();
    // Exchange the OAuth 2.0 authorization code for user credentials.
     $gPlusId = $request->get['gplus_id'];
    $client->authenticate($code);
    $token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
    // Verify the token
      $reqUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=' .
              $token->access_token;
      $req = new Google_HttpRequest($reqUrl);

      $tokenInfo = json_decode(
          $client::getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req)->getResponseBody());

      // If there was an error in the token info, abort.
      if ($tokenInfo->error) {
        return new Response($tokenInfo->error, 500);
      }
      // Make sure the token we got is for the intended user.
      if ($tokenInfo->userid != $gPlusId) {
        return new Response(
            "Token's user ID doesn't match given user ID", 401);
      }
      // Make sure the token we got is for our app.
      if ($tokenInfo->audience != CLIENT_ID) {
        return new Response(
            "Token's client ID does not match app's.", 401);
      }
      //$_SESSION['token']=$token;
    // You can read the Google user ID in the ID token.
    // "sub" represents the ID token subscriber which in our case
    // is the user ID. This sample does not use the user ID.
    $attributes = $client->verifyIdToken($token->id_token, CLIENT_ID)
        ->getAttributes();
    $gplus_id = $attributes["payload"]["sub"];

    // Store the token in the session for later use.
    $app['session']->set('token', json_encode($token));
    $response = 'Successfully connected with token: ' . print_r($token, true);
}

return new Response($response, 200);
})->method('POST');
```

In the html file I use ajax to call the previous PHP code:

```
connectServer: function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: window.location.href + '/connect?state={{ STATE }}',
    cache:false,
    contentType: 'application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
     // helper.people();
    },
    error:function(e){
      console.log(e);
    },
    processData: false,
    data: this.authResult.code
  });
```

But I always get an error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException: No route found for "GET /connect": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST).
How can I solve the error?

Comment: It's looks like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251126/no-route-found-for-get-user-register-method-not-allowed-allow-post

Comment: Yes. I watched but it did not solve the problem

Comment: Which means. If I change into "POST|GET" I would get another error: "Error: SyntaxError: DOM Exception 12"

Comment: This one looks like that one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714601/error-syntaxerror-dom-exception-12-on-tag-creation-using-jquery : )`Make sure you have jQuery loaded in your first example.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looks like this one: [No route found for "GET /user/register": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251126/no-route-found-for-get-user-register-method-not-allowed-allow-post)

You have to define `requirements` `_method` for you route, like:

```
routeName:
    pattern:  /yourPattern
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Sth:action }
    requirements:
        _method:  POST|GET
```